# polynomial such that p($\sqrt2$+$\sqrt3$)=0

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, extension-field

Are these following exercises equivalent?

1. Let $\mathbb R$ be an extension of $\mathbb Q$.Find a polynomial p(x) in $\mathbb Q$[x]-{$0$} such that p($\sqrt2$+$\sqrt3$)=$0$.

and

2.Find the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt2$+$\sqrt3$ over$\mathbb Q$[x]

Comment: I know the answer already exist in this site, but that's not what I'm asking @dxiv

Comment: What is the distinguishing difference in your question then?

Comment: that's just the title of the question @dxiv

Comment: That part is answered in the *body* of the linked question ($u^4 -10u^2 +1=0$) along with the explanation of how it was derived.

Comment: I am actually mildly surprised, if the linked thread is the first time this question has been handled.

Comment: so just to clarify, 1. is equivalent to 2.? @dxiv

Comment: @AaronMartinez no. Take $m(x)$ to be the minimal polynomial (which is unique). Then for any polynomial $f(x)$, $m(x)f(x)$ satisfies 1.

Comment: @AaronMartinez #1 asks for *a* polynomial, while #2 asks for the *minimal* polynomial. The two are not equivalent. Again, see the linked question and the answers under it.

Comment: @dxiv got it, thanks.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the present question does not ask for a minimal polynomial, only if two exercises are equivalent, meaning presumably whether an answer to either one of them yields immediately an answer to the other one. And the answer to that is: "No they are not (equivalent)" since an answer to 1. might not yield an answer to 2.

Comment: @Did but the answer of the second question answers too the first question?

Comment: @AaronMartinez Hmmm... if you have the slightest idea of the meaning of the words you use, you should not be asking this: yes, finding the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ suffices to find a nonzero polynomial whose evaluation at $\alpha$ is zero.

Comment: @Did I don't know how to feel about your answer haha :)

Comment: Then focus on the mathematical definitions involved, this will be more productive than wondering how you feel about this and that.

Comment: :( you're right man, I'll take it as an advice.I won't feel silly anymore I'm just gonna put mathematics in my mind, only mathematics. @Did